Can I exit România on a different passport than the one used for entering the country?
I entered România using my Romanian (living abroad) passport.
That passport was turned in to local authorities when I applied and was granted my Romanian ID card.
Can I use my American passport when leaving Romania?
Thank you.

What did the local authorities say when you asked them?

Show your Romanian ID card to exit passport officers, your US passport to the airline and if asked the other one as well.
If you only show your US passport on leaving Romania they rightly look for an entry stamp, showing your ID avoids that.
